# phpMailer image on body without attachmnet

Tags: php, phpmailer

How send image from phpMailer, without attachment, only on body?

With follow code i send img, but i need without attachment:

```
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/img/header_logo.png", "header_logo", "image/png");
$mail->Body = '<center><img alt="Logo" src="cid:header_logo"></center>';
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I solve put my path img server direct on 'src' attribute insteed 'cid'.

```
$mail->Body = '<center><img alt="Logo" src="http://xftaua.com/my/path.jpg"></center>';
```